# Помогите понять код

Tags: f#

Код подсчитывает количество цифр в строке, объясните пожалуйста как именно он работает?

```
"1234asdfgh" |> Seq.filter System.Char.IsDigit |> Seq.length |> printfn "%i";;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На C# этот код выглядел бы так:

```cs
    var digitCount = "1234asdfgh".Where(System.Char.IsDigit)
                                 .Count();
    Console.WriteLine("{0}", digitCount);
```

Что происходит? Строка `"1234asdfgh"` рассматривается, как *последовательность* символов. В C# строка реализует интерфейс `IEnumerable<char>`, которому в F# соответствует тип `Seq<char>`.

Затем к строке применяется оператор `|>`, который позволяет объединять вызов функций в цепочки. Запись `h(g(f(x)))` читается задом наперёд: первой вызывается функция `f`, а в записи она встречается третьей. С помощью оператора `|>` те же самые вызовы можно описать как `x |> f |> g | h`, то есть *берём `x`, примеряем к нему функцию `f`, затем `g`, затем `h`*.

Оператор `|>` называется *прямым конвейером* (pipe forward).

Мы вызываем функцию `Seq.filter`, которая аналогична методу расширения `Enumerable.Where`. Первым параметром должна идти функция-предикат, которая будет применяться к каждому элементу (символу) последовательности. В качестве такого предиката мы используем `System.Char.IsDigit` (статический метод из типа `char`), который получает на вход символ, и возвращает `true`, если этот символ цифра.

Дальше мы видим небольшое функциональное волшебство, которое называется *каррирование*. В вызове `Seq.filter System.Char.IsDigit` не хватает второго параметра, то есть непосредственно последовательности элементов, к которым будет применяться функция `System.Char.IsDigit`. В функциональном F# такая запись означает, что тут у нас создаётся новая функция, которая принимает только один параметр, а именно недостающую последовательность.

Помним, что `x |> f = f x`. В F# вызов функции `f` с параметром `x` записывается без скобок, так что `f x` значит то же, что в C# значит `f(x)`.

`"123asdfgh" |> Seq.filter System.Char.IsDigit` означает то же самое, что и `Seq.filter System.Char.IsDigit "123asdfgh"`.

Благодаря такой *обратной записи* мы в одну строку записываем последовательность преобразований над параметром, то есть над строкой `"123asdfgh"`.

Далее, получив последовательность, которая после фильтрации содержит только                 цифры, мы применим к ней функцию `Seq.length`, и та вычислит её длину. Иными словами, здесь мы получим количество цифр в первоначальной строке.

Наконец, это количество мы передадим в функцию `printf`, которая его и напечатает.

Резюмирую. Код читается так: берём цепочку символов, фильтруем её, оставляя только цифры, считаем количество цифр и печатаем его.

Comment: Не знаю C#), словесно можете объяснить?

Comment: @Denusko1488, попытался словесно. Обычно F# начинают учить те, кто знаком с C#, поэтому я и провёл аналогию.